# Compare two objects ignoring one key

Tags: javascript

I have two objects as below:

```
obj1 = {"a":"firstValue", "b":"secondValue", "c":"thirdValue157das15714daa4"} 
obj2 = {"a":"firstValue", "b":"secondValue", "c":"thirdValue1348sdfsf114sfs45fsd"}
```

I need to compare both objects ignoring the third key - value pair 'c'. Basically the comparison should return `true` ignoring the 'c'

Can anyone help me with an optimistic solution in angular or javascript

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following is one way to achieve this:

```js
const obj1 = {
  "a": "firstValue",
  "b": "secondValue",
  "c": "thirdValue157das15714daa4"
};

const obj2 = {
  "a": "firstValue",
  "b": "secondValue",
  "c": "thirdValue1348sdfsf114sfs45fsd"
};

const result = Object
  .keys(obj1)
  .filter(k => k !== 'c')
  .every(k => obj1[k] === obj2[k]);

console.log(result);
```

The above first filters out the non-required property and then compares the values of remaining properties in the two objects.

Comment: that's rather complicated to use different parameters with the same name `.filter(k => k !== 'c').every(k => obj1[k] === obj2[k]);`

Comment: @AlekseySolovey -- didn't get you. Are you asking about the same argument `k` being used in two different functions?

Comment: others may find it difficult to see that `k` used here are **two different** parameters, each with its own function scope, for `filter` and `every`. (_why not rename them?_)

Comment: @AlekseySolovey -- `k` denotes a key (acquired by `Object.keys`). Can be renamed, but doesn't matter much. One, with a basic understanding of JS, should not get confused about it.

Answer (score 3):

Simply

```
obj1.a == obj2.a && obj1.b == obj2.b
```

Or if an `a` and `b` are going to be dynamic, then store `keyToIgnore`

```
var keyToIgnore = [ "c" ];
var isEqual = Object.keys( obj1 ).every( s => keyToIgnore.includes(s) || obj1[ s ] == obj2[ s ] );
```

**Demo**

```js
var obj1 = {
  "a": "firstValue",
  "b": "secondValue",
  "c": "thirdValue157das15714daa4"
}
var obj2 = {
  "a": "firstValue",
  "b": "secondValue",
  "c": "thirdValue1348sdfsf114sfs45fsd"
}
var keyToIgnore = [ "c" ];
var fnCompare = ( obj1, obj2 ) => Object.keys(obj1).every(s => keyToIgnore.includes(s) || obj1[s] == obj2[s]);

console.log( fnCompare( obj1, obj2 ) )
```

Comment: will fail if any of the objects have a extra property though.

Comment: Also, if the values are objects, this will fail if the objects have different references. Just something to keep in mind.

Comment: @AyushGupta I know (first comment), but OP hasn't really fleshed out his/her question properly. I have added a solution for more dynamism though.

Comment: Yep, was just adding onto your answer

Answer (score 1):

You could check explcit every property of the objects.

```js
function check(o1, o2) {
    const filter = v => v !== 'c' ;

    var keys1 = Object.keys(o1).filter(filter),
        keys2 = Object.keys(o2).filter(filter);

    return keys1.length === keys2.length && keys1.every(k => o1[k] === o2[k]);
}

var obj1 = { a: "firstValue", b: "secondValue", c:"thirdValue157das15714daa4" },
    obj2 = { a: "firstValue", b: "secondValue", c: "thirdValue1348sdfsf114sfs45fsd" };

console.log(check(obj1, obj2));
```